# copy a folder- and all subfolders - without overwriting existing

Tags: vba, database, directory, fso

0

I am trying to create a backup database on a network drive using fso.folder copy. My intention is to move all files and subfolder within the folder, but if a file already exists on the backup drive, skip it, and copy the remainder of the files in the folder.

```
FSO.copyfolder Source:=Sourcefilename, Destination:=Destinfilename, OverwriteFiles:= False
```

However, the script errors when it finds the existing file. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `FSO` is a VBScript object. It does not accept parameters in this way (using `Destination:=Destinfilename, OverwriteFiles:= False`). The topic of `CopyFolder` function is `FSO.CopyFolder SourceFileName, DestinationFileName, False`, where the first two parameters are strings, meaning what their name suggests and the last one is `Boolean` type representing `Overwrite`. Please, try using it as I tried suggesting above and send some feedback

Comment: Thanks - when adjusting I still show the error the file already exists.

Comment: Yes, VBScript is nasty from this point of view. I will immediately post an answer with a solution to preliminary check if the folder exists...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testCopyFolder()
 Dim FSO As Object, SourceFold As String, DestinationFold As String
 
 SourceFold = "Source folder path"           ' ending in "\"
 DestinationFold = "Destination folder path" ' ending in "\"
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
 If Not FSO.FolderExists(DestinationFold) Then
    FSO.CopyFolder SourceFold, DestinationFold
 End If
End Sub
```

You can proceed in a similar way in order to copy files. Of course, using `FSO.FileExists()`...

Comment: Thanks for the help - I think the main issue I am running into is how to loop this for all files/folders within each main folder to skip what already exists within the new folder. As in if Main folder has test1.xslx and subfolder test2, and test2 has files within there to check - so on and so forth. is there a way to set up a loop within this to check all sub folders and file in the main folder?

Comment: @mphillies2008: Of course, it is. But this is a different question... You should mention this, at least. You did not show us anything of your code, except the problematic existing folders copying. **I** created and declared the necessary variable to be used in solving of your question...

Comment: @mphillies2008: Anyhow, it is not so complicate to iterate between all files, folders and subfolders, but do you define the place where to be copied?

Answer (score 0):

### Backup Folder and Its Subfolders Without Overwriting

- The following will backup a Source Folder to a Destination Folder i.e. copy missing folders and files.
- `TESTcopyFolder` is just an example how you could use the solution.
- It will call the initializing procedure, `backupFolder`, which will call `backupFolderCopy` and `backupFolderRecurse` when necessary.
- The declaration `Private SkipPath As String` and the three procedures have to be copied to the same (usually standard) module, e.g. `Module1`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private SkipPath As String

Sub TESTcopyFolder()
     
    Const srcPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\65412587\Test1"
    Const dstPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\65412587\Test2"
     
    backupFolder srcPath, dstPath
    
    ' Open Destination Path in File Explorer.
    'ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink dstPath

End Sub

' Initialize
Sub backupFolder( _
    ByVal srcPath As String, _
    ByVal dstPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal backupSubFolders As Boolean = True)
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    With fso
        If .FolderExists(srcPath) Then
            backupFolderCopy fso, srcPath, dstPath
            If backupSubFolders Then
                SkipPath = ""
                backupFolderRecurse fso, srcPath, dstPath
            End If
            MsgBox "Backup updated.", vbInformation, "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "Source Folder does not exist.", vbCritical, "No Source"
        End If
    End With

End Sub

' Copy Folders
Private Function backupFolderCopy( _
    fso As Object, _
    ByVal srcPath As String, _
    ByVal dstPath As String) _
As String
    
    With fso
        If .FolderExists(dstPath) Then
            Dim fsoFile As Object
            Dim dstFilePath As String
            For Each fsoFile In .GetFolder(srcPath).Files
                dstFilePath = .BuildPath(dstPath, fsoFile.Name)
                ' Or:
                'dstFilePath = Replace(fsoFile.Path, srcPath, dstPath)
                If Not .FileExists(dstFilePath) Then
                    .CopyFile fsoFile.Path, dstFilePath
                End If
            Next fsoFile
            'backupFolderCopy = "" ' redundant: it is "" by default.
        Else
            .CopyFolder srcPath, dstPath
            backupFolderCopy = srcPath
        End If
    End With

End Function

' Copy SubFolders
Private Sub backupFolderRecurse( _
        fso As Object, _
        ByVal srcPath As String, _
        ByVal dstPath As String)
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(srcPath)
    
    Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
    Dim srcNew As String
    Dim dstNew As String
    
    For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
        srcNew = fsoSubFolder.Path
        dstNew = fso.BuildPath(dstPath, fsoSubFolder.Name)
        ' Or:
        'dstNew = Replace(srcNew, srcPath, dstPath)
        If Len(SkipPath) = 0 Or Left(srcNew, Len(SkipPath)) <> SkipPath Then
            SkipPath = backupFolderCopy(fso, srcNew, dstNew)
            backupFolderRecurse fso, srcNew, dstNew
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```